# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null with $.each

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im using $.each to get the data from php via ajax but when i used it my browser saying this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null, cant find any answer.

```
 $('#search-button-applicant').click(function (){
             date_to = Date.parse($('#search-to-date').val());
            date_from = Date.parse($('#search-from-date').val());

            applicant_name = $('#search-applicant-name').val();




             if($('#search-to-date').val() == "" && $('#search-from-date').val() == "" && applicant_name == ""  )
            {
                 alert("you can not search");

            }

             else if($('#search-to-date').val() != "" && $('#search-from-date').val() == "" ||  $('#search-to-date').val() == "" && $('#search-from-date').val() != ""){

                 alert("you can not search");
            }

            else{
                   var date_to_val = $('#search-to-date').val();
                   var date_from_val = $('#search-to-date').val();
                   var loan_type_val = $('#loan-type').val();
                   var search_word_val = $('#search-applicant-name').val();



                 $.ajax({
                     type: "post",
                     url: "filter_search_window_get.php",
                     dataType:'json',
                     data: {'func_num':loan_type_val,'Date_To':date_to_val,'Date_From':date_from_val,'search_word':search_word_val},
                     success: function(data){

                            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                               $('#search-table-content-list').append("<tr><td style='width:7.5%;'><label>Date Filled</label></td><td style='width:9.5%;'><label>Date Released</label></td><td style='width:8%;'><label>"+data[i].last_name+"</label></td><td style='width:25%;'><label>Name</label></td><td style='width:7.5%;'><label>Term</label></td><td style='width:7.5%;'><label>Rate</label></td><td style='width:7.5%;'><label>Principal</label></td><td style='width:7.5%;'><label>Interest</label></td><td style='width:7.5%;'><label>Total</label></td></tr>");
                              });   

                            }
                     });
            }
        });
```

php:

```
$date_from = $_POST['date_from_val'];
$date_to = $_POST['date_to_val'];
$search_word = $_POST['search_word_val'];
$loan_type =$_POST['loan_type_val'];


switch ($loan_type){

case '1':

    tuition_get();

break;

case '2':
    salary_get();

break;

case '3':
    sss_get();

break;

case '4':
    ofw_get();

break;

case '5':
    business_get();

break;
}

function tuition_get(){
$date_from = $_POST['date_from_val'];
$date_to = $_POST['date_to_val'];
$search_word = $_POST['search_word_val'];

$query = "SELECT 
                                    a.applicant_id,
                                    a.last_name,
                                    a.first_name,
                                    a.created_date,
                                    b.form_type,
                                    b.form_id,
                                    c.stat,
                                    d.release_date,
                                    f.payment_term,
                                    j.form_rate,
                                    k.loan_amt,
                                   k.interest_amt,
                                    k.total_amt
                        FROM 
                                    applicant a
                        LEFT JOIN form_type b ON (a.form_id = b.form_id)
                        LEFT JOIN form_status c ON (c.status_id  = a.status_id)
                        LEFT JOIN applicant_loan_repayment d ON (d.applicant_id  =  a.applicant_id)
                        LEFT JOIN applicant_tuition_loan_dtl f ON (f.applicant_id  = a.applicant_id)    
                        LEFT JOIN form_term j ON (j.form_id  = a.form_id)
                        LEFT JOIN applicant_loan_repayment k ON (k.applicant_id  = a.applicant_id)

                        WHERE a.last_name LIKE '%$search_word%' OR a.first_name LIKE '%$search_word%' ";


             $result=mysql_query($$query)or die(mysql_error());



             $data=array();
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                $data[] = array(
                    'last_name'=>$row['last_name'],
                   'first_name'=>$row['first_name'],
                   'form_typ'=>$row['form_type']
                );
            }


        echo json_encode($data);


}

 function salary_get(){
    $date_from = $_POST['date_from_val'];
    $date_to = $_POST['date_to_val'];
    $search_word = $_POST['search_word_val'];


}


function sss_get(){
    $date_from = $_POST['date_from_val'];
    $date_to = $_POST['date_to_val'];
    $search_word = $_POST['search_word_val'];


}


function ofw_get(){
    $date_from = $_POST['date_from_val'];
    $date_to = $_POST['date_to_val'];
    $search_word = $_POST['search_word_val'];


}


function business_get(){
    $date_from = $_POST['date_from_val'];
    $date_to = $_POST['date_to_val'];
    $search_word = $_POST['search_word_val'];


}
```

im using $.each to get all the fetch data from the query and post it in a table using ajax but my $.each is not working properly and i dunno whats wrong with my code.

Comment: *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"* - Obviously you're using it on a wrong data-type. I suggest you do some basic debugging first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are posting a parameter named `func_num` via ajax, but trying to read it in php as `loan_type_val`.

Furthermore, *all* the data you are passing appears to be named differently than what you're attempting to read on the server-side.

If you're trying to send via post:

```
'func_num':loan_type_val,
'Date_To':date_to_val,
'Date_From':date_from_val,
'search_word':search_word_val
```

Your PHP server-side would have to be:

```
$loan_type = $_POST['func_num'];
$date_to = $_POST['Date_To'];
$date_from = $_POST['Date_From'];
$search_word = $_POST['search_word'];
```